# attempt to write a readonly database in Android2.1

Tags: database, android

**This is the error:**

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: attempt to write a readonly database
```

**This is my code:**

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();
try {
   // add new records
   ContentValues newRecord = new ContentValues();
   newRecord.put(Emergencydetails.EMERGENCYNUMBER, emergencyNumber.getText().toString());
   db.insert(Emergencydetails.EMERGENCY_TABLE_NAME, null, newRecord);
   db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: What is `mDatabase`? Where is the database located?  What line does your exception occur on?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. I have just shortened the table name. That's it.